# CSS Animation only works in Chrome and not in IE Edge

Tags: css, css-animations

This CSS only animates in Chrome but not in IE Edge: https://codepen.io/Tester2929/pen/RwapXrp

It seems it has to do something with this:

```
@keyframes animate {
  from {left: -100px;}
  to {left: 100%;}
    0%{
        transform: translateY(-250px) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    100%{
        transform: translateY(-250px) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 0.5;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell why it fails in IE Edge?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, it seems this works: https://codepen.io/Tester2929/pen/vYGxoRe

It looks like IE Edge was not reading the

```
  from {left: -100px;}
  to {left: 100%;}
```

and I changed translateY into translateX since I wanted the animation to go form left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Hi man your CSS does not work because some old browser does not recognize advance css so that you have to implement the webkit prefix to it just like below

```
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
 from {left: -100px;}
 to {left: 100%;}
 0%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-250px) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translateY(-250px) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 0;
}

100%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-250px) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translateY(-250px) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 0.5;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

}
@keyframes animate {
 from {left: -100px;}
 to {left: 100%;}
 0%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-250px) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translateY(-250px) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 0;
}

100%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-250px) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translateY(-250px) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 0.5;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

}
```

this is the same css as your just the difference is it has webkit prefix in it so that the browser can apply your styling

Comment: I'm afraid that your changes also do not work in IE Edge, see here your changes: https://codepen.io/Tester2929/pen/vYGxoRe

Comment: brother what I think is that your edge is very old because it's working on my system in edge alsso

Comment: The version I am using is : Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0     The one you are using is probably the one they just released.  I need it to work on my version as clients have that one.

Comment: What's strange is that the original animation here: https://codepen.io/mohaiman/pen/MQqMyo    Which was not modified at all works with my version of IE Edge, but not this one: https://codepen.io/Tester2929/pen/RwapXrp

Comment: yes what i think because of this property 
from {left: -100px;}
  to {left: 100%;}

Answer (score 0):

add the following script to your code and try again may it will work

[Download edge.js](http://transwebjp.com/transwebEdge_edge.js)

[Download edgeActions.js](http://transwebjp.com/transwebEdge_edgeActions.js)

[Download edgePreload.js](http://transwebjp.com/transwebEdge_edgePreload.js)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="edge.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="edgeActions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="edgePreload.js"></script>
```

Comment: I added your scripts to codepen: https://codepen.io/Tester2929/pen/RwapXrp   It still doesn't work.

Comment: How about we attack the question differently, which modification would you make so that the flying objects fly from left to right in this codepen? https://codepen.io/mohaiman/pen/MQqMyo

Maybe you have a solution to that which is simpler?

Comment: hey now check this https://codepen.io/ali_asgher/pen/qBZmWdX?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=8cb2a7d016272ca0c7c0be07dfedeee003fe7a52-1598459916-0-AQRrdMQd7ieqaasY0qmoyPmg3LtY4ClmXFg6YokYYdSsEtQg8bZjnax8G9kb0dvgCZtS84AqEgWdXKWuXmJqZ_baz0_zzCOTS7xOa37k4Kl19QnMytBkplBg3ReNmFL_JQoUzeaWVn31Gd6ZGJugoEfqFgwbvdOww2eFYRh3-xMCetIiDZJ3NjmJZjucqEfOIvidIdBVbdFQX24X3qDEVXa-ffBkdNzl6ElrKdjrfInQBcR12BXnJfr6J8BzCWaKT2wxfOi4Ak1n97tXt-cvPrh7hHUOuCGPPck52U2FAk2al6xsZz1XXIhFV6WKvwLY-TuZBD6BUzxsKF6CJO7dYBnvl0cqGYvsw9uUcrgaV691
is it working

Comment: The animations in this link you made do not go from left to right in IE Edge, they only do that in Chrome. https://codepen.io/ali_asgher/pen/qBZmWdX